# Where on Earth is the highest none polar magnetic fields?

Tags: geophysics, geomagnetism, mapping, field-measurements, ore

Is there anywhere that magnetic ore deposits are strong enough to have a magnetic field that would be stronger then 
Earths' magnetic poles by proximity?

I'm not asking [Where on Earth is the magnetic field intensity stronger?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/13854/where-on-earth-is-the-magnetic-field-intensity-stronger) In other words where might be a natural place on Earth that would over power a compass and then some? Is there a map of those magnetic field lines minus the Earths' polar magnetic field lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In other words where might be a natural place on Earth that would over power a compass and then some

Just about anywhere where the rocks are rich in iron. This would occur near iron ore, basalt, gabbro, and similar iron-rich rocks. You really don't need a lot of magnetite in the rock for this to move the compass needle. You don't even need magnetite - chromite or pyrrhotite rich rocks may be enough to move the compass needle off.

This is a common problem when navigating only using a compass in basalt rich areas. A good historical example is that of Tasmania. You can read about it the following article:

[Magnetic rocks—their effect on compass use and navigation in Tasmania](https://eprints.utas.edu.au/13644/1/1997_Leaman_Magnetic_rst.pdf)

As for a map, you're probably looking for a magnetic anomaly map.

[Here's an attempt to make a global](http://geomag.org/models/wdmam.html) , or this one from [USGS](https://crustal.usgs.gov/projects/namad/), or this one being [offered for sale](https://ccgm.org/en/maps/113-carte-des-anomalies-magnetiques-du-monde.html).