# Can living where magnets are abundant provide a mini-magnetoshere?

Tags: geology, models, magnetosphere, rock-magnetism

Are there a mini-magnetosphere within the magnetosphere similar to mini-magnetosphere found on the Moon? Is there a map of these areas that would resemble the white swirls in the picture below?

The white areas extending up to 360 km and are the safer areas where one could be protected to a degree. 
[image]

Are there areas on Earth that could have this magnetic crustal properties as the moon has and would it add or supplement the protection of Earth's magnetosphere?

[image]
Source: http://lunarnetworks.blogspot.com/2010/10/grand-lunar-swirls-yielding-to-lro-mini.html

Comment: These might be useful: [Earth Magnetic Map](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/magnetic-map-shows-earth-youve-never-seen-it-180962612/), [Earth Magnetic Anomaly Grid](https://ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag/emag2.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can living where (rare) earth magnetic ore is abundant provide any protection from cosmic radiation?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/17611/can-living-where-rare-earth-magnetic-ore-is-abundant-provide-any-protection-fr)

Comment: @Spencer not s duplicate the other question asks about just rare earth magnets. Where this one asks about less caustic magnetic rock and the magnetospheres they make on Earth that may resemble the moons magnetospheres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near to the Earth's surface there are small variations in the Earth's magnetic field, but these don't play a role in providing the magnetosphere which protects the Earth from charged particles emanating chiefly from the solar wind.